# The CDI Stereotype is not worked with EJB Session Bean

Tags: ejb, cdi

I've a CDI Sterotypes which contains some of InterceptorBinding as the following: -

```
@Inherited
@InterceptorBinding
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({
    ElementType.METHOD,
    ElementType.TYPE})
@Documented
public @interface MyInterceptable {

}

@Interceptor
@MyInterceptable
public class MyInterceptor {
    @AroundInvoke
    public Object perform(InvocationContext context) throws Exception {
        log.info("My Interceptor begin.");
        Object result =context.proceed();
        log.info("My Interceptor end.");
        return result;
    }
}

@Stereotype
@MyInterceptable
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({
   ElementType.TYPE
   })
@Documented
public @interface MyStereoable {

}
```

When I define this Sterotype at the non-EJB it is worked correctly. The message is printed before and after the doing1() execution.

```
@Singleton
@MyStereoable
public class MyCustomized {
   public void doning1(){
     //print something.
   }
}
```

Anyhow, when I've tried to use this with the Stateless EJB, it is not worked. There is no any message printed by the Interceptor.

```
@Remote
public interface HelloServiceable extends Serializable {
   void doning2();
}

@Stateless
@MyStereoable
public class HelloService implements HelloServiceable {
    public void doing2() {
       //Print something
    }
}
```

Then I mix the case 1 and case2 as the following: -

```
@Stateless
@MyStereoable
public class HelloService implements HelloServiceable {
    @Inject
    private MyCustomized myBean;

    public void doing2() {
       this.myBean.doing1();
       //Print something
    }
}
```

The MyCustomized can be intercepted and the message is printed, but not for the Stateless EJB.

I'm not sure if I am misunderstand or confused about the CDI and EJB or not. Could you please help to advise further? Thank you very much for your help in advance. I'm looking forward to hearing from you soon.

Regards,

Charlee Ch.

Comment: In what container are you testing this?

Comment: I'm using Glassfish 3.1.1 for windows with Weld-1.1.4-Final. Please note, I download the weld-osgi-bundle-1.1.4.Final.jar and replace it to the GF_HOME/glassfish/modules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've changed my project from EAR/EJB project to standalone Web project. The CDI Stereotype is now worked with EJB Session Bean.

I've created a small demonstration at [github](https://github.com/charleech/arquillian-evaluation/tree/master/centralized-interceptor). Please take note, It uses the JBoss Arquillian for testing.

I hope this information maybe useful.

Regards,

Charlee Ch.